# How do you compare only certain bits in data type?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to learn a bit about emulation and I'm trying to think of how I can decode opcodes.  Each opcode is a short data type, 16 bits.  I'd like to be able to compare only specific sets of 4 bits.  For example: there are multiple opcodes that start with 00, such as 0x00E0.

I'd like to be able to compare each of these values in either bit or hexidecimal form.  I was thinking maybe something along the lines of bit shifting to bump of everything else off so that the bits I don't care about would zero out.  That may cause issues for the center bits and will require additional steps.  What kind of solutions do you guys use for a problem like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple [bit manipulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C). You can mask the relevant bits with

```
int x = opcode & 0x00f0;
```

and compare the resulting value

```
if (x == 0x00e0) {
    /* do something */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a bit mask, which has the bits set that you care about. Then use the `&` operator to zero out everything that you don't care about. For instance, say we want to compare the lowest four bits in `a` and `b`:

```
uint16 mask = 0x000f;
if ((a & mask) == (b & mask)) {
  // lowest 4 bits are equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily create the mask of "nbits" and and shift "pos" number of bits and do comparision

```
uint32_t mask = ~((~0) << nbits);

if( (num(mask << pos)) == 0x00e0 ) {
    /* Do something */
}
```

Comment: should be `~0ul << nbits` - otherwise you have left-shift into the sign bit which is undefined behaviour

Comment: Right shift operator will result in undefined behavior, Left shift operator will always give the same result for signed and unsigned.